# C# division off by one bit

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do floating point division in C#, and getting a result that isn't quite what I expected.

```cs
float l = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 0x0a, 0xd7, 0xa3, 0x3c }, 0);
float h = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 0x8f, 0xc2, 0xf5, 0x3d }, 0);
float v = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 0x4a, 0x65, 0xb1, 0x3d }, 0);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in System.BitConverter.GetBytes((v - l) / (h - l))) sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
System.Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());  // Expected: 6b8b2a3f, Actual: 6a8b2a3f
```

It's really close, but the mantissa is just one less. Is there something atypical about how C# does floating point arithmetic?

Comment: It's interesting, because I would expect `(v / (h - l)) - (l / (h - l))` to result in `6a8b2a3f`.  Does C# automatically distribute the subtraction across the division or something (to avoid loss of precision)?

Comment: Bear in mind that it's explicitly contemplated for the CLR (and happens on x86/x64) that a larger precision data type is used for intermediate results.

Comment: It is allowed to store intermediate results in a float80 register. Although I think in debug it doesn't do that if you store those results back into a float32 variable

Comment: Interesting, so I assume as soon as the value is actually assigned to some sort of lvalue, it uses an actual float, but any intermediate rvalues may (or will?) use a larger precision data type?

Comment: Anybody have a link to documentation on this behavior?